# How to find a $\theta$ function verifying this property?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, special-functions

Let $r>4$ and $n>1$ be positive integers. Intuitively, the infinite sum

$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{2m}{r^{m^2}}$$ is related to a $\theta$ function. However, I cannot find a way to calculate this function. How to find a $\theta$ function verifying this property?